# Paypal IPN seems to use cached versions of my php handler script

Tags: php, caching, codeigniter, paypal

Im developing a codeigniter based ipn handler script for my shopping app. It seems that the Paypal sandbox uses cached versions of my response script. I get an Email with the post-values everytime i send an ipn test. I changed the email template like 2 hours ago but the ipn script sends the emails with the old layout.

Thant makes debugging my ipn Variables a pretty bad mess. I tried setting the header-cache-control to "must-revalidate" but the results appear the same.

It is just like paypal stores a proxied version of my file and uses it over and over again.

Do you have any ideas about this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had to bet, I would bet against this being a caching issue. PHP scripts usually don't emit any caching headers (but of course, do make sure to check e.g. using Firebug), and the purpose of the whole thing would be defeated if PayPal actually *listened* to such caching instructions.

I would triple- and quadruple-check the URL that PayPal calls to see whether there is a second version of the script hanging around that doesn't get updated - maybe a case of `Index.php` vs. `index.php` or something? That often is the reason.

The only caching culprit I can think of is a reverse proxy on your web server's end. But you're not mentioning having one, so I'm assuming there is none.

Comment: you were right, i went home and had to think about it again and again and as you suggested i took a look at the form that submits to paypal in the first place. it calls a totally different method in another controller which i forgot to delete. I assumed the wrong url for the ipn call. thanks for the hint.